# how to use 'actions-on-google' libray in aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, actions-on-google

In actions-on-google , both the request and response object need to provide as input to this library. but in lambda function, only the request object exists.

So how can i override it ?

in aws lambda the format is

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) { // event is the request object , the response is provided using the callback() functon 
}
```

the actions-on-google object is created as :

```
const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
const app = new DialogflowApp({ request: request, response: response });
```

Comment: Did you get the actions javascript sdk running on AWS Lambda? Or is it not working cause of the different approach Lambda function are using for response and request handling? Is this what you mean with reponse object as input? So as input to the actions on google sdk package?

Else you can build the response json by hand its realtive simple. I can send you if  I interpreted your question correct.

Comment: yes , your interpretation is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a Google Action to work on AWS Lambda, you need to do 2 things:

- Code your app in a way that it's executable on Lambda
- Create an API Gateway to your Lambda Function which you can then use for Dialogflow Fulfillment

I believe the first setp can't be done off-the-shelf with the Actions SDK. If you're using a framework like [Jovo](https://www.jovo.tech/), you can create code that works for both Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant, and host it on AWS Lambda.

You can find a step by step tutorial about setting up a "Hello World" Google Action, host it on Lambda, and create an API Gateway here: https://www.jovo.tech/blog/google-action-tutorial-nodejs/

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of Jovo. Happy to answer any further questions.*

Answer (score 1):

This is only a half answer:
Ok, so I dont think I can tell you how to make the action on google sdk correct working on AWS Lambda. 
Maybe its easy, I just dont know and need to read everything to know it.

My, "easy to go", but at the end you will maybe have more work solution, would be just interprete the request jsons by yourself and responde with a message as shown below

This here would be a extrem trivial javascript function to create a extrem trivial JSON response.

Parameters:
***Message*** is the string you would like to add as answer.
***Slots*** should be an array that can be used to bias the speech recognition.
(you can just give an empty array to this function if you dont want to bias the speech).

And ***State*** is any kind of serilizable javascript object this is for your self to maintain states or something else It will be transfered between all the intents.

This is an standard response on an speech request.
You can add other plattforms than speech for this, by adding different initial prompts please see the JSON tabs from the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#json

```
function answerWithMessage(message,slots,state){
      let newmessage = message.toLowerCase();
      let jsonResponse = {
            conversationToken: JSON.stringify(state),
            expectUserResponse: true,
            expectedInputs: [
                {
                    inputPrompt: {
                        initialPrompts: [
                            {
                                textToSpeech: newmessage
                            }
                        ],
                        noInputPrompts: []
                    },
                    possibleIntents: [
                        {
                            intent: "actions.intent.TEXT"
                        }
                    ],
                  speechBiasingHints: slots
                }
            ]
        };
      return JSON.stringify(jsonResponse,null, 4);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .. but the problem does not solve by it, In action-on-google the response is provided by executing  app.handleRequest(responseHandler);   - which automatically send the response. but in aws lambda the response is provided by   callback(err,responseObject);         So  what exactly need is the responseObject from actions-on-google need to be retrieved. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes I guess I am probably the wrong person for an easy solution for that problem:  Not sure how to get an express equivalent reponse object in lambda, the event handling there is different. For Google action sdk it use the send(), some of the header functions, the error codes etc. out of the response object I guess, So you can probably try to implement some similiar object in Lambda but it is maybe a bit work. Maybe you can also get it from somewhere or make the google action sdk working without it.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://www.jovo.tech/ its a framework witch will be doing alexa and google home https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/server/aws-lambda with lambda support